# Getting page views and last updated date within a Liferay Web Content Template

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I need to include the date the web content was last updated and the number of times the web content has been viewed within my Liferay 6.1 Web Content Template.

What's the best way to go about getting this?

Comment: You can check attribute of assetEntry object related to your web content for viewcount, also modifiedDate of assetEntry or journalArticle object can give you last updated date

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya How do I go about getting the assetEntry from the web content template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity
For the modified date you can use the variable `$reserved-article-modified-date.data`  and for the count of view

```
#set ($groupId = $themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId())
#set ($journalArticleLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService"))
#set ($ja = $journalArticleLocalService.getArticle($getterUtil.getLong($groupId),$getterUtil.getString($reserved-article-id.data)))
#set ($resourceprimKey = $ja.getResourcePrimKey())
#set ($assetEntryLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService"))
#set ($assetEntry = $assetEntryLocalService.getEntry("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle", $resourceprimKey))


count view = $assetEntry.viewCount
```

Freemarker

```
<#assign JournalArticleLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService")>
 <#assign assetLinkLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetLinkLocalService" )>
 <#assign assetEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService" )>
 <#assign getterUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil"] />
 <#assign currentArticle = JournalArticleLocalService.getArticle(getterUtil.getLong(groupId),.vars['reserved-article-id'].data)>
 <#assign currentArticleResourcePrimKey = currentArticle.getResourcePrimKey()>
 <#assign currentArticleAssetEntry = assetEntryLocalService.getEntry("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle", currentArticleResourcePrimKey)/>

 view count = ${currentArticleAssetEntry.viewCount}
modifydate = ${.vars['reserved-article-modified-date'].data}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Expression serviceLocator is undefined" error. Any ideas why?

Comment: You have to active the service locator for template in portal-ext.properties